# How to create 'import dummy data' option in custom wordpress plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

i am creating a plugin and in that plugin i want to create my own import dummy content option. For that i have searched on internet but haven't found anything useful yet. So anyone can tell me the process how to create the custom option to c\import dummy content

Comment: It would be nice to mark an answer as solved / or give a comment at least that it did not (*yet*) help/worked as wished*. Please see the [help center](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) why.

Comment: Okay i will do this if i will do work on it

Comment: Thanks for this information i'll keep this in mind in future

Answer (score 1):

I think that this would do the trick.

**Edit**
Of course you can leave the line starting with `if(` and the curly bracket after `return` away when you want to have it for all posts/custom post types.

```
/**
  * Create dummy content
  * @param [type] $content
  * @version WP4.4.2
  */
function wpse218668_default_dummy_content( $content ) {
    global $post_type;

    if( $post_type == 'CustomPostType' ) { // cpt name or post
        // Add here your dummy txt
        $content = 'Add here your dummy text';

    return $content;
    }
}
add_filter( 'default_content', 'wpse218668_default_dummy_content', 99 , 1 );
```

> Read more in the [Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/default_content/)